# Join pairwise adjacent array elements to each other with a delimiter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
var array=["kiran", "1998", "roshan", "1997", "Vidyut", "2004", "mahesh", "2005"];
```

I have to combine it and make is like

```
combined=["kiran-1998","roshan-1997","Vidyut-2004","mahesh-2005"];
```

I have to combine the `array[n]` with `array[n+1]` with '-' in between. How can I do that in JavaScript?

I have tried `.join("-")` method in it but it joins the whole array, but I don't know how to join only two of them

I tried this for loop code also but it also shows error

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i=i+2)
{
    updateArray[i] = array[i].join("-");
}
```

I was trying to join first element and second element but got stuck here

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: We aren't going to do your homework for you. If you have a specific question about a specific problem that you are facing, then you can ask it here, but you *must* show that you have made an effort to try and solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried to join it using .join() but it joins the full array together. So, I am confused like how to do it @Andreas

Comment: What is `merged`? What error are you talking about? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: @Andreas sorry I corrected it now you can check it

Comment: @SumnerEvans:` We aren't going to do your homework for you`  is not appropriate :) Imagine yourself in the shoes of OP. He is just a new kiddo. He will learn with time how to ask a better question. I think the way Andreas has replied is showing true professionalism. Hats off to Andreas. 1) That OP is learning how to use SO better 2) He did came up with edits now :)

Comment: @FaizanLambe your `for` loop method is close. A few things to think about: 1) does index `i` exist in `updateArray`? (hint, it probably doesn't). 2) what data does `array[i]` contain? 3) what data does `array[i+1]` contain? (this one is key)

Comment: I am voting to reopen :) Now that OP has comeup with the minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Andreas ok so how can I do it with for loop then? I am not able to understand

Comment: @FaizanLambe here's another hint: what does `array[0] + '-' + array[1]` return?

Comment: @FaizanLambe: I have provided you with 2 solutions. First one is more performant...Use that... That will take 4 iterations only :)

Comment: @Andreas: Hi mate :) OP needs one more vote to re-open his question. Is the question still lacking anything for it not to  open ! OP has made edits even Summer Evans has been very kind lately :) Do vote to re-open it. This will boost the confidence of OP as well. And will be helpful for community :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Based on OP's EDIT.

**SOLUTION-1:**

```js
var array=["kiran", "1998", "roshan", "1997", "Vidyut", "2004", "mahesh", "2005"];

const updatedArray = [];
for(i=0;i<array.length;i=i+2)
{
    updatedArray.push(`${array[i]}-${array[i+1]}`);
}

console.log(updatedArray);
```

**SOLUTION-2:**

You can use ES6 `map` and `filter` to achieve this: Try this :)

```js
var array=["kiran", "1998", "roshan", "1997", "Vidyut", "2004", "mahesh", "2005"];

const updatedArray = array.map((item,index,arr)=>{
  if(index%2 === 0){
    return `${item}-${arr[index+1]}`;
  }
}).filter(item=>item!==undefined);

console.log(updatedArray);
```

Comment: I'd probably separate them in two different arrays with a filter, and concat them in the next step. I think it'll be a cleaner solution, even though it requires more than one line :)

Comment: I think that will not be as efficient solution as the above one my Friend :)

Comment: Imho that's a terrible way... A simple `for` loop (or `.reduce()`) would be easier.

Comment: I tried a for loop but not working i guess i made a mistake please can you show me how its done @Andreas

Comment: reduce() is a HOF as well :) So on every iteration callback will be called. But yes reduce() could reduce our code..OH BOY REDUCE reduces code :) Awesome

Comment: @FaizanLambe Add that attempt in your question, so we have something to work with (and can reopen the question)

Comment: Faizan kahaan sai hain app? :)

Comment: @Andreas: Dear Andreas I believe we should not have closed this question without giving OP a chance... OP is new here :) Also I believe language in the comment by Summer Evans is unacceptable here !!!

Comment: Main mumbai se hu @ImranRafiqRather

Comment: please check it above @Andreas

Comment: Jazakallah for the solution. You were very helpful as well as @Andreas. Thank you both for helping me solve this

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather I had one more question what is back tick " ` " used for. When I am using single quote or double quote I am not getting the output but when I am using back tick i got the output

Comment: These are called template-literals introduced in ES6.  They are used for string interpolations :) Yes, with double quotes, we'll have to go with concatenation using `+` sign. Do search about template literals you will get to know more about these :)